# .NET Core ClaimsIdentity list of claims is empty

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity, claims

I am currently working on a .NET Core project using bearer tokens for authentication. When I generate a new token and try to add claims to the corresponding **ClaimsIdentity**, its list of claims somehow remains empty at runtime.
I assume I am not generating the claims correctly, but could not find the error.

This is the code which generates a token and adds the claims:

```
private string GetToken(string username, DateTime? expires)
    {
        var audience = _authenticationOptions.Value.JwtTokenAudience;
        var issuer = _authenticationOptions.Value.JwtTokenIssuer;
        var rsaKey = _authenticationOptions.Value.SecurityKey;

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        IEnumerable<Claim> claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username) , new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "DemoRole")};

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
        var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(rsaKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature);
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var token = handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Audience = audience,
            Expires = expires,
            IssuedAt = now,
            Issuer = issuer,
            NotBefore = now,
            Subject = claimsIdentity,
            SigningCredentials = signingCredentials
        });

        var writeToken = handler.WriteToken(token);
        return writeToken;
    }
```

Screenshot when debugging the list of claims:

[image]

Note that I am not using the Identity Framework. So using the UserManager to get the corresponding claims is not possible:

```
new ClaimsIdentity(await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user))
```

Comment: Have you tried expanding the results view in the debugger to enumerate the claims, as explained by the debugger?

Comment: "Result View" is enumeration, not list, so expand it in VS  and you will see it at runtime. Test app works fine with your code

Comment: I just realized the screenshot was a littelbit misleading. The results view does indeed contain the correct claims. The ClaimsPrincipal provided by the User variable of a controller did not. However I found out that the error was not the above code, but the token I sent with the Get-Request when debugging. Thanks for the quick replies!